# Drag object stick to mesh faces -partly working - unless I add as a child... Three.js r60

Tags: three.js

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50584977/index2b.html

(Can't seem to get three.js examples to work on jsfiddle)

If you look at the above example, and you drag one of the cubes across the sphere, it 'sticks' to the sphere, and rotates to the face normal. (Sort of, unless you try on the back side of the sphere.)

Problem:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50584977/index2.html

All that is changed is I'm adding the dragged cube as a 'child' of the sphere when you let go of the mouse. So drag a cube onto the sphere, then let go, then try dragging the same cube again, see what happens.

It seems to get worse if you rotate the scene, then try dragging again.

Why is it doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add one object to another, the child's `position`, `rotation`, and `scale` become relative to the parent's. So, when you add your sphere to a cube, you'll need to adjust the sphere's position first. Conceptually, the simplest way to do this should be to just subtract the cube's position from the sphere's.

Comment: The math looks at the vector going out from the Face centroid, and rotates the dragged item's orientation to match. The idea in my mind was 'it shouldn't matter' if it's a child or not. The reason I want it to be a child is so I can rotate the group later.

Comment: Well, it does matter that it's a child. :-) The rotation is probably fine, it's the position that's getting compounded.

Comment: var localPoint = intersectsRay[1].point; ---- so this is returning world coordinates? This is the point on the sphere where the mouse intersects. So I'd have to convert that to local coordinates?

Comment: OK I figured it out it's way easy. To make object being dragged (SELECTED) Look At at the face normal of any face within a mesh you're dragging it across....    var p = intersectsRay[1].point;       SELECTED.position = p ;
SELECTED.lookAt( intersectsRay[1].object.localToWorld(face.normal.clone()));  --- Almost starting to get the hang of Three.js.